# Should I use "vehicle" or "vehicle's"?

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns

Here are my constructions:

> 1. Only minimal signs of corrosion on the **vehicle body** surface which have been removed.
> 2. Only minimal signs of corrosion on the **vehicle's body** surface which have been removed.

So my question is, should I use 'vehicle body' or 'vehicle's body'?

Comment: Are you trying to say "...the surface of the body of the vehicle...", or "...the surface of the 'vehicle body'...", or "...the 'body surface' of the vehicle..."? Or is a 'vehicle body surface' a thing? It's difficult to give an exact answer without this information.

Comment: Also, it appears these sentences lack a predicate: "which have been removed" appears to be a restrictive clause describing the signs of corrosion. If this sentence is supposed to indicate that corossion has been removed, then the "which" in the sentence is out of place and should be deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since OP is effectively using ***body*** as an [*attributive noun*](http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/d26.html) (noun functioning as an *adjective* - in this case modifying the explicit noun ***surface***), I think it's more natural to echo the same usage with ***vehicle***. But this is just a stylistic preference.

In principle, it's even "grammatical" to refer to *the **vehicle's body's** surface*. But using two consecutive possessives like this is generally seen as "awkward" from the native speaker's perspective.

---

If we consider a simpler case with only *one* modifier before the noun...

> 1: The **car** windscreen is badly scratched
>    2: The **car's** windscreen is badly scratched

...native speakers would normally use the possessive (#2) if context implies the need to distinguish it from some *other* windscreen *(The truck is okay, but the car's windscreen is cracked)*. If that's not the case they'd probably use the attributive noun (#1). As a "rule of thumb", using the possessive in such contexts places more emphasis on the *modifier*, rather than on the noun itself.

Answer (score 6):

Both "the vehicle body surface" and "the vehicle's body surface" are correct, and mean the same thing.  Use whichever version makes more sense to you.

If you diagram the sentence, the two diagrams will be slightly different.  In "the vehicle body surface", "the" is attached to "body surface".  In "the vehicle's body surface", "the" is attached to "vehicle".  If there is one vehicle, with one body, this difference does not matter.

The example is not a complete sentence.  It might be from a form that is usually filled out quickly, or from a list.  The list might be beneath another partial sentence, which completes the sentence.